# PHP save to file script giving errors after upgrade to PHP 7.0

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, php-7, fread

I have rather simple script that is supposed to add new line of string to a file.

```
if (isset($_POST["score"]))
{
$myFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/xx/zz.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);

$File = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/xx/zz.txt"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
$Data = $_POST["score"]."\n".$theData; 
fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
fclose($Handle); 
}
```

After upgrading to PHP 7.0 I get errors:

```
fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/zzz/public_html/zzz.php on line 7
fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/zzz/public_html/zzz.php on line 8
```

Could anyone explain why this error shows up and how it can be fixed? What is it with PHP 7.0 that caused it suddenly to stop working?

Comment: are you sure that it's not reading the old system files from the previous php version? what does `phpinfo()` show and does that file initially have content? If the file's empty, it will throw that error. Check permissions also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//First, see if the file exists
if (!is_file($myFile))
{
    die("<b>404 File not found!</b>");
}
```

Or you can try to use [The SplFileObject class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) - an object oriented interface for a file.

Answer (score 1):

When `fopen()` fails it returns false. false is not a resource, thus the warning.

You'd better test `$fh` before injecting it as a resource-like argument:

```
if($fh = fopen($myFile, 'r')) {

}
```

Comment: That would mean that fopen failed to oped file $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/xx/zz.txt"
But I've checked and file is there. Nothing changed neither in script nor in files on FTP. Why would upgrade to PHP 7.0 suddenly cause fopen to fail?

Comment: How about checking for permissions? You can use error_log() to ensure your DOCUMENT_ROOT is what you believed it to be.